# Restore Thunderbird CC field as baseline

Tags: thunderbird

Thunderbird used to have a CC field but in version 78.6.0 it is hidden by default and can only be restored by clicking on the "Cc" button for every mail I write. How can I restore the CC field as as active by default and save the mouse click for every mail?

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible natively in Thunderbird 78:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1304562

However, there is an add-on that allows this (among others):
https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/nostalgy_ng/